# ctrl+alt+l not activating screensaver

Tags: shortcut-keys, 14.04, screensaver

When I first installed Ubuntu 14.04 the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> would activate the screensaver. Now, after I had to do a reinstall that shortcut locks the account and goes to lock screen. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> also locks the account. How can I get it back to where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> activates the screensaver and the setting in the gear on the top right says "Activate screensaver" and not "Lock".

Answer (score 0):

Go to system settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts, and add a shortcut with the following command `gnome-screensaver-command -a`

Comment: Another option is `gnome-screensaver-command -l`